# Convert HTML4 to HTML5 on visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html

What is the best way to convert existing HTML4 asp.net Web form Project to HTML5 
Suppose that i change to HTML5 Do the HTML4 Tag still works ?

Comment: Rewrite it? [‍](http://www.google.com)

Comment: You could try feeding the site into the validator at http://validator.w3.org/, selecting HTML5 as the target to validate against, and correct all of the errors and warnings that pop up. Though you're better off writing it over from scratch.

Comment: Add more information on question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot was changed between HTML4 and HTML5. The ideal here would be to simply rewrite your application. Even if there exists a tool to convert an HTML4 page that validates to an HTML5 one, this tool would probably leave out most of the nice things that were added in HTML5.

That being said, if you just want to make a "valid" HTML5 page from an HTML4 one, you should take a look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/

It details the changes between the two versions, pinpointing exactly what you would have to update.